# Equality of hash of string and hash of the reverse of a string

Tags: function, hash

Is it possible to write a hash function in such a way that hash of a string is equal to the hash of the same string but reversed? e.g.

hash("life") == hash("efil")

hash("life") == hash("life")

Comment: Maybe sort chars in string and then hash them. But it will fail for words like `cat` and `act`.

Comment: `function hash(_) { return 42; }` – You might have to restrict the problem a little more…

Comment: Do you need it for comparing strings?

Answer (score -1):

It would most likely defeat the purpose of it being a good uniform hash function, but sure, you can define a function like that. Anything that maps data of arbitrary size to data of fixed size is a hash function.

You could e.g. sort the characters in the input before passing the string to some other hash function, example in Python:

```
def myhash(s):
    return hash(''.join(sorted(s)))

myhash("life") == myhash("efil")
```

returns True.

Another option, as sketched before in the comments:

```
def myhash2(s):
    return hash(''.join(sorted([s,''.join(reversed(s))])))

from itertools import permutations
for r in sorted(((myhash2(s),s) for s in (''.join(p) for p in permutations('life')))):
    print r
```

returns

```
(-8040601677570703892, 'efil')
(-8040601677570703892, 'life')
(-7809799233501675124, 'feli')
(-7809799233501675124, 'ilef')
(-7087163641342373728, 'feil')
(-7087163641342373728, 'lief')
(-3309334617147859636, 'ifel')
(-3309334617147859636, 'lefi')
(-1342443318618769016, 'flei')
(-1342443318618769016, 'ielf')
(-1101501415991241164, 'elif')
(-1101501415991241164, 'file')
(-94298563527211992, 'elfi')
(-94298563527211992, 'ifle')
(1475311783909651192, 'efli')
(1475311783909651192, 'ilfe')
(1616670693919962800, 'eifl')
(1616670693919962800, 'lfie')
(1783747732969301136, 'iefl')
(1783747732969301136, 'lfei')
(1880557847288313568, 'fiel')
(1880557847288313568, 'leif')
(4933084291912123320, 'eilf')
(4933084291912123320, 'flie')
```

I still like the comment/solution of @deceze best...

Comment: But it will return true for `cat` and `act` and I am sure that we can found much more examples.

Comment: It wasn't specified that random permutations should have different hashes. One could come up with some other constructs, of course, you could e.g. reverse the string and append both strings, in the lexicographically order. But with hashes, there will always be collusions anyway.

Comment: Those sneaky hashes colluding behind our backs…

Comment: It should not be the case with random permutations. The lexicographical ordering might be more work, but still, I can't understand why lexicographical ordering will work for these two permutations only.